# How to decide on the number of microservices and whether to have common jars

Tags: spring-boot, api, microservices

I have 3 micorservices one that serves request from UI and the other that serves request from public apis and the third which does some data processing and storing the data provided from the kafka topic by UI/public.

I have written common service and dao jar for the services, as the data is coming from the common data source.

If I dont have common service/dao then lot of code will be duplicated.

I am now feeling that this is causing coupling between the services.

Is it the right design?

Answer (score 0):

Using a common DAO across microservices is right if it is making development faster and easier to understand for everyone, and wrong if it's not. You are right that this is creating some coupling between the services, but it's coupling that you could easily do away with if the DAOs for the services began to diverge. Since the final shared package will be inside each service's runtime, there would be zero issues introduced if one of the other services decided to stop using the DAO and use a different one.

That being said, you may have a larger coupling issue if all three services are using this DAO to connect to a **shared database**. If each is dependent on the same tables/schema, it makes it very hard for one service to diverge from the others and make independent schema changes without impacting the others.